# EF6 Primary Key Violation When adding Complex Item

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an Entity set of classes where there is a recipe; that recipe can have multiple Ingredients (handled with a foreign key), each ingredient can have a component. There are several sets of tables that follow a pattern similar to this, which several layers

When I add a single recipe, which contains some ingredients that ultimately lead to the same component, I get an error message saying that adding the recipe to the database causes a primary key violation on the components table. Is there a way to tell Entity that if a component has the same primary key value, it should be updated not inserted? I get that you can do this at the top level using `context.Recipes.AddOrUpdate(recipe)`, but how could I achieve it for each of the sub levels down into the tree structure?

here are some summarised examples of the entity classes that I have in place:

```
public partial class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public partial class Ingredient
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}

public partial class Component
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

//in the : DbContext class, there is this:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Recipes)
        .WithMany(e => e.Ingredients)
        .Map(m => m.ToTable("Recipe_Ingredient_Link").MapLeftKey("IngredientId").MapRightKey("RecipeId"));
```

Am I receiving this error message because the two components with the same Id have got different `Ingredients` ICollections associated with them, causing Entity to treat them as different objects? If so, how can I get round this problem? If not, what is the problem?

I generated the classes from an existing database and haven't changed the code it made for me, other than to turn off lazy loading.

Comment: When you are creating a new recipe, are you actually creating ingredients and components at the same time or are you just linking to existing entities? If your answer is the first: why?

Comment: I am importing the first ever recipe into the database, which is coming from a JSON file, that has all the linked ingredients and components and so on. I am adding all of the info by building a single recipe class, which contains all the ingredients etc and then adding that to the database. When I start the `Add` all the tables are empty and it fails on the first recipe, the fifth component (which is actually the same as the fourth component).

Comment: You should show the code that causes the exception. It can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem here is that in your conversion from JSON to C# objects you get a separate object for each component in the JSON. This means even if two components have the same ID it's two different objects like you have also described. This is as illustrated here:

```
Recipe #1
|
|-- Ingr. #1
|   |-- Comp. #1
|
|-- Ingr. #2
|   |-- Comp. #2
|
|-- Ingr. #3
    |-- Comp. #1  // Same ID as the one for Ingr. 1, but it's a separate C# object
```

When you try to add a hierarchy of objects (by just adding the top-level `Recipe`) Entity Framework will see each C# object as a separate entity. So even if two objects share the same ID, there's no logic telling EF how to handle that. I.e. how should it behave if the other properties (apart from the ID) are different?

So what I believe you would need to do instead is to ensure that no two objects have conflicting IDs. You have to iterate through your objects and make sure that if two components have the same ID, you need to remove one of them and have the `Ingredient`s link to the same `Component` object, as illustrated here:

```
Recipe #1
|
|-- Ingr. #1
|   |----------------|
|                    |
|-- Ingr. #2         |
|   |-- Comp. #2     |-- Comp. #1 // Now they point to the same C# object
|                    |
|-- Ingr. #3         |
    |----------------|
```

I'll let you think about how to code that.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense given the context. I had hoped that registering the primary keys with EF would make it run the comparison for me. Since there is a time constraint on this project, I guess I'll put identity columns on my tables and insert the duplicates as new objects, which will still allow the foreign keys to find out which goes where. I'll try to sort this out in the next phase, but I think your explanation is correct and has put me on the right path.